# Use Auth facade in API routes (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, laravel-api, laravel-vue

I am looking to use `Auth::user()` in the `CompanyController` sitting in the `api.php` route file in **Laravel 8**. Like

```laravel
Route::get('team', [CompanyController::class, 'index']);
```

But if I do so, I won't be able to access Auth in the following code in the `CompanyController` file.

```laravel
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function index(Request $request)
    {

        /**
         * Role 1 => admin, 2 => hr, 3=> member
         */

        if (Auth::user()->role <= 2) {

            return ['company' => Auth::user()->company, 'team' => Auth::user()->company->users];
        }
    }
```

So what I have done now to achieve what I need is prefix api to the routes sitting in the `web.php` route file instead.

```laravel
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('team', [CompanyController::class, 'index']);
}
```

After googling around, I am more or less aware that Laravel Sanctum may solve the issue, and it's happened because of the Token driver used in the Api routes. But I'm wondering if there is any easy alternative solution for this. It looks like it would take a while to customise the login page with Sanctum.

What I want is still to take advantage of the initial login page set up with the Breeze starter kit. At the same time, after the user logs in, they can get access to Auth.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Auth::user()->role <= 2) {
```

Here you assume that the user is authenticated and you need to put this route with the authentication middleware. For example:

```
Route::get('team', [CompanyController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth');
```

If you will use Laravel Sanctum, you need to protect routes (only if really needed)

```
Route::get('team', [CompanyController::class, 'index'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Documentation:

- [Laravel Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware)
- [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)